# Setting up SNMP on Windows After Downloading the Services

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, snmp, snmpd

I would like to know how you set up SNMP on a windows computer. I downloaded the SNMP tools as an optional service, but I don't know how to finish setting them up, so that I can use them. [I attached a screenshot of the "Optional Features" page where it shows the SNMP and WMI SNMP programs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roknG.png)

Comment: "I downloaded the SNMP tools as an optional service", so what exactly did you download? Describe clearly or add a screenshot so that others don't need to guess.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.